# NSString/NSMutableString strange behaviour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

OK here is nsmutablestring

```
data = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"&cb_games%5B%5D="];
```

Now when ever I try to print or use this string I get big number instead of %5B and %5D not sure why this is happeing any help would be apritiated

thanks

Comment: Can you tell post the big numbers so we can know what they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString * data = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"&cb_games%%5B%%5D="];
NSLog(@"%@",data);
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason you get unexpected output is that `'%'` is used as ***conversion specifier*** in *printf* and obviously *NSLog* and *NSString* formattings. You need to escape `'%'` if you don't want it to be interpreted as a conversion specifier. You can escape `'%'` by preceding it with another `'%'` like `'%%'`.

Your string should look like,

```
@"&cb_games%%5B%%5D="
```

And the *@August Lilleaas's* answer is also noteworthy.

Answer (score 2):

`stringWithFormat` is basically `printf`, and it attempts to replace your percentages with values that you haven't provided, which is why wierd stuff happens.

```
[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Hello: %d", 123];
// @"Hello: 123"
```

If you want a mutable string  from a string, try this:

```
[NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Abc %2 %3"];
// @"Abc %2 %3"
```

Answer (score 0):

The % is used for string formatting and stuff.  I imagine you need to escape the character or something, possibly with a slash.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to write?

```
data = [NSMutableString stringWithString@"&cb_games%5B%5D="]
```

Comment: sorry had to do some formatting in the string just removed for simplcity